# ITokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync throws NullReferenceException

Tags: jwt, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-graph-api, bearer-token

In the Startup.cs of web api app, I have the following code. When this runs it throws NullReferenceException at GetAccessTokenForUserAsync.  Any idea what I am missing?

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
        {
            var tokenAcquisition = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices
                .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
                {
                    var token = await tokenAcquisition
                        .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { "User.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All", "GroupMember.Read.All" }, user: ctx.Principal);
                    request.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                }));

            // Get user information from Graph
            var groups = await graphClient.Me.CheckMemberGroups(new[] { Constants.GroupId })
            .Request()
            .PostAsync();
        }
    };
});

services
.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(this.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
.AddMicrosoftGraph()
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

NullReferenceException:
[image]

**Update:**
I Just figured out that the issue is because I am missing the authenticationScheme: JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme parameter value for the GetAccessTokenForUserAsync method call but now I am getting this exception message ""IDW10104: Both client secret and client certificate cannot be null or whitespace, and only ONE must be included in the configuration of the web app when calling a web API. For instance, in the appsettings.json file. "

Am I not using a token to call the endpoint? Why do I need a client secret or certificate?  Can I do without?  The token that the web API get from the caller is from an authenticated user and the web API has delegated permission of the user?
I am new to this so please bear with me. Thanks!

**Update2:**
After adding the client secret, I am getting the following exception:

[image]

[image]

**Update3:**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var principalProvider = new ClaimsPrincipalProvider();

            services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var tokenAcquisition = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices
                                .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();

                            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
                            {
                                var token = await tokenAcquisition
                                    .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { "User.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All", "GroupMember.Read.All" }, user: ctx.Principal, authenticationScheme: JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                                request.Headers.Authorization =
                                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                            }));

                            var groups = await graphClient.Me.CheckMemberGroups(
                                new[]
                                {
                                    Constants.GroupId
                                })
                            .Request()
                            .PostAsync();
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                };
            });

            services
            .AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(this.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddMicrosoftGraph()
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Yes , as you are calling azure ad configurations from appsettings, please include client secret in that  ,as web app which calls web api is confidential and needs somes ecret to include while recieving token to validate app access

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you how to fix the following exception that I get as shown on Update2? "MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. "

Comment: in my humble opinion, what you have is a web api app, which can be protected by azure ad, so the incoming request should have a bearer access token in the request header. but you write a `OnTokenValidated` event and  `new DelegateAuthenticationProvider` inside the event. As you know Delegate Auth requires users to sign in so that it can then generate another access token for you, in your webapi, it doesn't contain a sign in feature, so you met the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It makes a lot of sense to me but when I tried to extract the token from header like the following and use it in the API call.  I am getting the below error. 
var token = ctx.HttpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization].ToString();
Error:
Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2022-11-01T06:07:05
 request-id: 01184a66-6de4-4191-a2e0-f8ba0547c6e4
 client-request-id: 01184a66-6de4-4191-a2e0-f8ba0547c6e4
ClientRequestId: 01184a66-6de4-4191-a2e0-f8ba0547c6e4

Comment: After removing the prefix "Bearer " from the token I am getting error "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.".  From this message it seems to me that the token from the header is not intented for calling Graph. It looks like I need to call tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync to get the token that I need to call Graph. The question is how to use delegate auth without getting the MsalUiRequiredException that I was getting before...

Comment: please check scopes or give valid token parameters where valid audiences can be both appIdUri orciletId of app

Comment: try giving scope as User.read and check or please provide the code in startup class

Comment: The first parameter of GetAccessTokenForUserAsync has the scopes as the first parameter already isn't it? Update3 contains the most of the code in startup class as it relates to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the scenario in my environment using postman.***

- I excluded client secret/certificate while getting the token to the application for the user.
- I received similar error :

[image]

Basicallly, when Web apps call web APIs we need some valid secret token to give access to secure app.In general they are confidential client applications. So the  secret that is registered in the azure ad for the app must be passed  during the call to Azure AD endpoint to get a token.

Then I provided a valid value of secret to the endpoint and received to token successfully to call my Api.
In your app it must be included in

***`appsettings.json:`***

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "[xxxxx]",
    "TenantId": "<tenantId here>"

   // To call an API
   "ClientSecret": "[Copy the client secret added to the app from the Azure portal]",

 },
 "MyApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta",
    "Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    }
}
```

[image]

***And then received the group members successfully.***

[image]

**Reference**: [Build a web app that authenticates users and calls web APIs - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview)